# How do I use a DrawableGameComponent in an SL & XNA app on Windows Phone 7.5?

Tags: silverlight, xna, windows-phone-7.1

When using a class derived from `Xna.Framework.DrawableGameComponent`, it requires a `Game` object for the constructor, where do I get this from?  The combined Silverlight and XNA project doesn't seem to have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Game object, or GameComponents in a combined Silverlight and XNA application.  From [Microsoft's App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/migration_guide_moving_to_silverlight_xna):

> Moving to this new model does have some trade-offs—namely, the Game
>   class and related functionality, such as GameComponents, are not
>   present. The rest of this guide attempts to answer the common
>   questions about how to migrate to the new application model. It also
>   acts as an educational tool for starting in the new model to draw some
>   parallels back to your existing knowledge.